# How can I make an environment variable available outside of a KSH script?

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have a KSH script that exports an environment variable (`export SOME_VAR=123`)

After running the script my current shell is unaffected and `echo $SOME_VAR` produces nothing.

I tried running `. myScript.ksh` but got the following error:

> .: Permission denied.

Permissions for `.` are `drwxr-xr-x`

Any idea? (I'm not root)

Comment: What permissions does `myScript.ksh` have? Is it readable? (Using `. name` is the correct way, since a process cannot update its parent's environment, which is why running the script "as a script" did not work.)

Comment: The script's permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x` - and it runs when invoking it without `.` before it.

Can it be related to the fact my shell is TCSH?

Comment: Yes, it could. (See answer below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using *tcsh* as your shell:

1. tcsh does not have a `.` command – only `source`.

   ```
   > source myScript.ksh
   ```

   In *sh*, *ksh* and *bash* shells, "`.`" is a built-in command, *unrelated* to the "current directory" usage of "`.`"

   In *csh* and *tcsh*, no such built-in exists (the equivalent is named "`source`"), and using `.` will attempt to execute *a directory*, hence the "Permission denied" error.
2. tcsh is a *csh* derivative, and uses a very different syntax for setting environment variables:

   ```
   setenv SOME_VAR 123
   ```

   This matters because using `.`/`source` causes the file's contents be executed *in the current shell*, meaning they have to be valid *tcsh* syntax.

Comment: Thank you - so to summarize, I cannot do what I wanted with a KSH script executed in a TCSH shell, right?

Comment: @RonK: Right. If you want to change enviroment variables of your current shell, you have to use `.` or `source`, and for that you must use a script written specifically for your current shell.

Comment: @RonK: There is another possibility — write a script, in any language that *outputs* (echo's) the apropriate `setenv` lines, then tell tcsh to evaluate that script's output: `eval \`./myscript\``; this is somewhat fragile, though — you have to be very careful with output quoting.